# What is the meaning of <property> tag in [servlet-name]-servlet.xml of Spring Web MVC?

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, servlets, spring-mvc

I got the following bean declearation in my [servlet-name]-servlet.xml of my Dynamic Web Project using Spring Web MVC?
I have read quite a lot of documents but stil couldnt understand what is the purpose of having those property tags?

```
<bean name="abcController" parent="defController" 
    class="abcController">
    <constructor-arg ref="staticService" />
    <property name="commandClass" value="abcCommand" />
    <property name="property2" value="search" />
    <property name="property3" value="true" />
    <property name="formView" value="/someValue" />


</bean>
```

I know that the property could a field in abcController class, but there is no such a field named formView in abcController class!
Does anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That xml file is used to create fields without having those fields coded in the file itself.

```
 // This is used to Start the ApplicationContext Container and to get the Bean of AbcCotroller

ApplicationContext context = 
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("[servlet-name]-servlet.xml");

abcController obj = (abcController) context.getBean("abcController");
```

You could later on use the beans in your code:

```
obj.getFormView(); //this will return '/somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Bean.java
 public class SampleBean{
 private String message;
 public void setMessage(String message){
     this.message=message;  //setter injection            

        }
  public void ShowMessage(){
  system.out.println("Message"+message);
       }
  }

  //Main.java
   Class Main{
     public Static Void Main(String args[]){
```

//TO Start the ApplicationContext container

```
         ApplicationContext applicationcontext = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationCOntext("Spring.xml");
  //To Read the SampleBean
        Object o=applicationcontext .getBean("SampleBean");
       SampleBean sampleBean=(SampleBean)o;
 //Invoke the Method
            sampleBean.ShowMessage();
         }
     }
//Spring.Xml
```

// you need to configure some more nameSpace which are required for Spring and  Xml

```
    <bean id="sampleBean" class="SampleBean">
     <property name="message" value="this is the  use of property Tag"/>
   </bean>

   //output :This is the use or Property Tag
```

explanation: when we want to perform Setter Injection we go for the Property
Tag
In spring we have some dependency injections like setter,constructor,interface,lookup method injection
when we use the Setter Injection first Dependent class object is create and next the dependency class object is created